# Old Unix apps: are Solaris PC Netlink and SCO AFPS the same program?

Tags: samba, netlink, unixware

I'm using AFPS on Unixware, just for curiosity and learning (I already know there is Samba and AFPS is not supported since the 2008).
Searching on net I see a product which has the same paths (/var/opt/lanman) and some identical commands (net, euctosjis, etc.) called Solaris PC NetLink
Simple question: is the same program maybe re-licensed or renamed?
I also found a manual of a old server for AT&T and Siemens Unix called "Advanced Server for UNIX" which has the same commands of AFPS.
I think probably is the same program re-licensed or renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris PC Netlink clearly declares its origins:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/overview/ds-netlink-150144.pdf

> Based on AT&T's Advanced Server for UNIX

I could not find a similar declaration of the history of SCO AFPS, but it appears the [the source code of AT&T Advanced Server for Unix was licensed and/or sold to several commercial Unix vendors](https://esj.com/articles/1999/03/24/open-systems-huh.aspx) and so acted as a common starting point for DOS/Windows file and printer sharing support for several commercial Unix products:

- already-mentioned Solaris PC Netlink
- some versions of Digital's DEC PathWorks for Digital Unix?
- HP's Advanced Server/9000 for HP-UX (later replaced by a Samba-based product)

So it would not be at all strange if SCO AFPS originally started as a port of AT&T Advanced Server for UNIX to SCO, and then developed into its own product from that shared original source. The similarity of commands and pathnames certainly suggests that this might be the case.